# Calling a function before defining it in python

Tags: python

Why I can call a function before defining it ?

Note: This isn't a full code , it's just a part

Here:

```
self._check_key_down(event) # HERE
```

.

```
class Game:
    def _check_event(self):
        '''Keyboard and mouse events'''
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
 
 
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               self._check_key_down(event) # HERE
 
 
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_key_up(event)
 
 
    def _check_key_down(self,event):
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.ship.moving_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.ship.moving_left = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You aren't calling it until control reaches that point during interpretation (CPython). It's only checked for syntax during the class definition/compilation stage, not that the function exists. Try it with `self.asdjhasdh()` and see if it compiles to bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you save this in a file named `game.py` and in another file you have `from game import Game` or something similar. This `import` statement loads the entire `game.py` file and executes it line-by-line. When it sees the `class ...` declaration, the interpreter inserts that class in the current namespace and then continues to find all fields and function definitions. These are all stored at the time of the import. So that when you later do something like

```
game = Game()
game._check_event()
```

all member methods are already known. Now when `self._check_key_down()` event is called inside this method, the interpreter already knows that the method exists because it was parsed during the earlier import.